# How to remove toolchains from Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, toolchain

I've lots of Android NDK revisions, starting 6 up to latest 14 (to test building of native code). In order to save storage space i've deleted `mips*` toolchains from `./toolchains/` (from android ndk 10c to be more detailed) as i don't need them for sure.

Now while trying to build library code with Gradle i'm getting the following error:

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mipsel-linux-android

though in `Application.mk` i have only `armeabi-v7` and `x86`:

> APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86

In `build.gradle` i have :

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 16
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

  defaultConfig {
    ...

    ndk {
      abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
    }
  }

  externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
      path 'jni/Android.mk'
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

How can i delete unnecessary toolchains properly?

Comment: There seems to be little value to test buildablility of your code with old NDK releases. NDK releases keep backwards compatibility with older platforms quite well (only r15, currently still in beta, has dropped android-9, shifting to android-14 as minimum, covering 99% of devices still active on May, 2). Anyways, your gradle integration can only work with one NDK revision. Keep it recent, and keep all toolchains for this revision.

Comment: This is not true 100%. Eg. V8 requires specific versions of toolchain which is just absent in the latest revisions. Also there are some significant changes in linking, f.e. there is a difference between 10e and 11 (`Changed libc++’s inline namespace to std::__ndk1 to prevent ODR issues with platform libc++`) which leads to that library can be linked with 10e, but can't with 11

Comment: Why is it worthwhile to ensure code compilability on NDK 10e?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use gradle, you can't. Gradle checks for all the toolchains as part of a sanity check.

If you're using the absolute latest NDK (r15 beta 2) and the canary Studio/Gradle, then you *might* be able to do this by marking the toolchains you remove as "deprecated" in `$NDK/meta/abis.json`.

Comment: i was able to remove some toolchains without any errors so i'm still curious what is Gradle algorithm to check toolchains existence